# Scope problems - Injected parent class is undefined after $emit event in child instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

1. I'm binding Vue events to a parent class and then injecting that class into children, which then injects it into a child class.
2. The parent events work fine down the line i.e. parent, children and child.

**THE PROBLEM**

If I fire off an event in the child class the children class will receive the event, but the children class has become the Vue instance, meaning that if I run this I get the Vue instance . I think it is how I'm binding the events in children.

[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/MatrixMe/y8gtopf3/81/)

```
var vue  = new Vue();

var events = {
    fire: function(event, data = null){
        vue.$emit(event, data);
    },
    listen: function(event,callback){
        vue.$on(event, callback);
    },
};


class Parent {
    constructor(options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
}

// IMPORTANT - We bind the events to the parent class
Object.assign(Parent.prototype, events);


class Children {
    // We bind the events to the parent class
    constructor(parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.children = [];

        const events = {
            REMOVE_CHILD: this.removeChild,
            CHILD_ADDED: this.childAdded,
            CHILD_REMOVED: this.childRemoved,
        };

        // we set the events using parent instance
        _.forEach(events, (a, k) => {
            this.parent.listen(k, a);
        });

        // we add first child 
        this.addChild({name:'First Child'})  
    }

    addChild(child) {
        var newChild = new Child(this.parent,child);
        this.children.push(newChild);
        //console.log('------- child added ', this);
        this.parent.fire('CHILD_ADDED', newChild);
    }

    removeChild(child) {
       // This works We get the child
        console.log('------- remove this child', child);
       // this.children = _.filter(this.children, (c) => c.id !== child.id);

       // We get an undefined
        console.log('------- PROBLEM - this parent is undefined', this.parent);

        // This fails as the instance is Vue from events
        this.parent.fire('CHILD_REMOVED', child);
    }

    allTheChildren() {
                return this.children;
    }

    childAdded(child) {
        console.log('------- child added', child);
    }
}

class Child {
    constructor(parent,child) {
            this.parent = parent;
          this.child = child;
          this.name = child.name;

          console.log('------- child class', this);
    }

    removeChild() {
          this.parent.fire('REMOVE_CHILD', this.child);
    }
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    children: {},
        service: new Children(new Parent({}))
  },
  computed: {
    getChildren() {
       return this.children;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    // example 
        this.children = this.service.allTheChildren();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can do this instead:

```js
_.forEach(events, (f, k) => {
  this.parent.listen(k, f.bind(this));
});
```

Comment: thanks a million. I had tried something similar, but kept binding it to the foreach function which threw an error. This makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in JS `.call()` in [Mozilla call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

If I change the following in child class (original)

```
    _.forEach(events, (a, k) => {
        this.parent.listen(k, a);
    });
```

to the following it maintains its current scope context.

```
    _.forEach(events,  (f,k) => {
        this.parent.listen(k, (child) => {
            f.call(this,child);
        });
    });
```

Working example [JS Fiddle Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/MatrixMe/pmbnr6w3/15/)